# Does the $I$-torsion functor commute with inverse limit?

Tags: commutative-algebra, local-cohomology

> Let $I$ be an ideal of a commutative ring with unit. Is $\Gamma_I(\varprojlim M_j)\cong \varprojlim(\Gamma_I M_j)$?

Any reference of the proof or a counterexample is appreciated. It seems this should not be true, but i don't have a counterexample.

Comment: Although the example below shows that this is false in general, it might be worth mentioning that there is a canonical map $\Gamma_I(\varprojlim M_j) \to \varprojlim(\Gamma_I(M_j))$, which is an isomorphism if the inverse system is finite (i.e. only finitely many $M_j$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple counterexample: let $R=\mathbb Z_p$ the $p$-adics, and $m=p\mathbb Z_p$ its maximal ideal. Then $\Gamma_m(\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ for all $n\ge 1$, while $\Gamma_m(\mathbb Z_p)=0$.

Comment: $\Gamma_m(\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z) = p^{n-1}\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$? So all the maps in the inverse system are zero, so the inverse limit is zero in this case, and the isomorphism holds?